# How to hide password in Kendo grid

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, kendo-grid

I have a grid with password column and I want to hide password as its type is password.

I do something like this but it didn't recognize the Password(in template).

```
  {field: "Password", title: "Password", editor: passwordE, 
 template: ( Password == null ? ' ' : '●'.repeat(Password.length))
```

passwordE Function:

```
  function passwordE(container, options)    {
  $('<input type="password" required data-bind="value:' + options.field + 
 '"/>').appendTo(container);
 };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample dojo with what I think you want.
https://dojo.telerik.com/IMuxEMUX

Although I do have a couple of questions:

1. Why are you bringing back the password in the first place? (Is it actually needed)
2. Hopefully your passwords are encrypted in some way otherwise someone can just look at the underlying datasource and see all the unencrypted passwords. (so negating this process entirely)

Although I am not a fan of this inline templating with logic and prefer to have an external template this should hopefully help you get your specific example working.

Assuming I have understood that you want the none edited text to be shown like this "●●●●●●●●●●" then the template i have created will achieve that for you.

```
  #if(data.ProductName == null){# 
        <span></span>
    #}else{# 
     #= "●".repeat(data.ProductName.length)#  
    #}#
```

obviously youjust need to swap out the ProductName for the password field in your datasource.

The important thing here is to see the use of `#` to signify when we are presenting something back to the screen and when we are doing javascript and breaking in and out of it.